# Are you able to have sex in Jannah 24/7?

Tags: sex, jannah

And can you also tell me if you’re allowed to tell your wives in jannah to do anything for you? Like anything that would be considered haram in this world.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complicated question as no one will have a definitive answer to your current concern since we are talking about the unseen; no one has ever gone and lived in Paradise (Jannah) and returned to tell us how it really is.

> **Thou seest the wrong-doers fearful of that which they have earned, and it will surely befall them, while those who believe and do good
> works (will be) in flowering meadows of the Gardens, having what they
> wish from their Lord. This is the great preferment.** – (As-shura,
> Chapter 42, Verse 22)

And in another verse:

> **Say: Is that (doom) better or the Garden of Immortality which is promised unto those who ward off (evil)? It will be their reward and
> journey’s end. Therein abiding, they have all that they desire. It is
> for thy Lord a promise that must be fulfilled.** – (Al-Furqan, Chapter
> 25, Verses 15-16)

All we know is what Allah mentioned in the Quran and what Prophet Muhammad (SAWW) told us, which is very limited in scope; what we are sure about is that Paradise is beyond comprehension.

We cannot compare Paradise to our earthly life, since it is completely different.  Allah, the Most Generous, will make everyone who enters it satisfied to the utmost so that they will never complain or desire anything more.

Answer (score -1):

in jannah your able to have all of your desires fulfilled and that includes sex and other sexual fantasies you may want to have fulfilled  that may have not been possible in this world

Comment: It is always good to cite the base of your answer (essentially Quran, Hadith) Mention Aya/verse and link to stable sites like tanzil.org and sunnah.com.